# Qt - 'thread' file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to build a C++ program with threads in Qt, but it gives me an error: 'thread' file not found. In Xcode I can run a program with threads!. How can I solve this issue ?

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please explain how you call the compiler.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean!                                                          Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)  that's it?

Comment: Try with CONFIG+=c++11 in your .pro file, as `thread` is new in C++11

Comment: Does the file thread.h exists ? Why not QThread ?

Comment: It works with CONFIG+=c++11. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`<thread>` is a header introduced with C++11. To enable C++11 for your project, add this to your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```